# Jersey: It's possible get from ResourceInfo the Interfaces that getResourceClass() implements?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using jax-rs with jersey,
I implemented a ContainerRequestFilter, and I have annotated ResourceInfo object with @Context annotation. 
there is a way to have not only the class but also its implemented interfaces directly from ResourceInfo? Or there is another way to get these information?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean if you have

```
@Path("...")
public class Resource implements IOne, ITwo {
```

you want to get `IOne` and `ITwo`. For this, just use [`Class#getInterfaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces--)

> `public Class<?>[] getInterfaces()`
>
> Determines the interfaces implemented by the class or interface represented by this object.

---

For anyone for which the above is still unclear, `ResourceInfo#getResourceClass` returns the `Class` object for the resource class. From the returned `Class` object, you can call `getInterfaces()`

```
Class<?>[] ifaces = resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getInterfaces();
```

Comment: Thank you @peeskillet, I already know this solution, but I will find a method, if exists, to retrieve this info directly from [ResourceInfo](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) or in another variable of jersey context

Comment: _"Or there is another way to get these information?"_. What more are you looking for? You can look at the API for ResourceInfo and see you aren't going to get much from it but the class and method. Best you're going to get is `resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getinterfaces()`